# Dynamically added Highcharts series with min and max

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I currently have a Highcharts chart that has several tabs that allow the user to show various data on the graph/chart. So I am dynamically adding series for each of those data points. This all works great.

However, I would like to set the `min` and `max` (instead of Highcharts just automatically determining the `min` and `max`) for the `yAxis` for two of those data points, so that when comparing their data on the graph they line up with each other. However, I can't seem to find a way to set the `min` and `max` of the `yAxis` for the added series.

Below is what I have currently:

```js
window["chart"].addAxis({
    id: 'Data',
    title: {
        text: 'Graph',
        enabled: true
    },
    lineWidth: 0,
    lineColor: '#000000'
});
window["chart"].addSeries({
    data: groupingData,
    name: 'Graph',
    type: 'line',
    color: '#000000',
    yAxis: 'Data'
});
```

How would I force the certain `min` and `max` for `yAxis` when dynamically adding this series?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else is looking for the answer, I found out that you can just set min and max when addAxis is called:

```
window["chart"].addAxis({
     id: 'Data',
     title: {
         text: 'Graph',
         enabled: true
     },
     lineWidth: 0,
     lineColor: '#000000',
     min: minNumber,
     max: maxNumber
)}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use setExtrimes() for this:

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.events.setExtremes
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.events.setExtremes

```
chart.yAxis[0].setExtremes();
```

Comment: I had seen that in the documentation, however wouldn't that change the extremes for the whole chart? I just want to set the extremes/min/max for just this certain axis/series that I am adding. Is it possible to set the min/max for just that certain axis/series?

Comment: But what exactly does this chart look like? Does each series have a separate axis? Or do you just have multiple series on one axis and want to scale them independent of the data?

Comment: Each series has a separate axis.

Comment: Is that possible? It seems hard to believe that it wouldn't be possible... I just can't find any documentation or examples of it anywhere!

Comment: Maybe you will be able to do this just on chart.update() and set the new min and max there? You can see a simplified demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Lq9t57e8/